# Eigenvector and eigenvalue for differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

My friends and I have been struggling with the following problem, and don't understand how to do it. We have gotten several different answers, but none of them make sense. Can you help us?

**Problem statement:** Let $V$ be the vector space of real-coefficient polynomials of degree at most $3$. Let $D:V \rightarrow V$ be the differential operator; $D(p(x))=\frac{d}{dx}p(x)$. Give an example of an eigenvector for $D$. What is the corresponding eigenvalue?

We ended up getting that $\frac {d}{dx}p(x)=\lambda p(x)$, so that $p(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Think intuitively; differentiate a polynomial with degree at most 3.  Then the resulting polynomial will be a degree less.  Is there any scalar that can bring you back to a degree higher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict $D$ to the finite dimensional subspace $V_n$ of polynomials of degree $\leq n=\deg p.$ Then $D^{n+1}=0$ on $V_n.$ Hence the only eigenvalue of $D$ is $0$ and the eigenvectors a constant polynomials.

Comment: Hi, why are the eigenvectors constant polynomials, if the eigenvalue is 0? Shouldn't the eigenvectors be 0 as well, because they are 0*something?

Comment: $0$ is never an eigenvector by definition.